# jQuery.Validate - validation after typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate plugin.
How can I make it validate input only after the user finishes typing?

The default behavior which returns error from first typed letter doesn't seem to be very user friendly IMO.

Comment: Call it on [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) or after a timeout from keyup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are numerous options available in the plugin API.

try setting `onkeyup: false`  the default is `true`

Rference: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Answer (score 0):

as strange as it may feel, i would use "change".

[here's my example code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seanmcmills/nFPep/) for your convenience.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#the_text").live("change", function() {
          alert("the value has changed")
        })

      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" value="original_value" id="the_text">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't think you realize that validate plugin is in use and sets it's own event handlers that OP is trying to customize behavior of